# Foundation tabs and Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zurb-foundation

I am putting a google map inside of a foundation tab and it loads as grey with no controls.  If I resize the browser in any capacity then the map will show properly, but I don't know how to get it to refresh/resize the map when the specific tab is selected. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
<style>
    #propertymap {
        width: 100%;
        height:480px;
    }

</style>

<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
  <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel1">Pictures</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2">Virtual Walkthrough</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel3">Map</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel1">
    <p>Pictures</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2">
  <p>Virtual Walkthrough</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel3">
    <div id="propertymap"></div>
    <script>
    var latitude={tag_latitude}, //the tag is for the business catalyst web app 
        longitude={tag_longitude};

    var marker;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('propertymap'), {
    center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
    zoom: 15
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
  });
  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
</script>
<style>
    #propertymap {
        width: 100%;
        height:480px;
    }

</style>

<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
  <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel1">Pictures</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2">Virtual Walkthrough</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel3">Map</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel1">
    <p>Pictures</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2">
  <p>Virtual Walkthrough</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel3">
    <div id="propertymap"></div>
    <script>
    var latitude={tag_latitude}, //the tag is for the business catalyst web app 
        longitude={tag_longitude};

    var marker;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('propertymap'), {
    center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
    zoom: 15
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
  });
  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
</script>



  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap"></script>

  </div>
</div>
```

http://vprintz.businesscatalyst.com/property-list/4-bay-meadows is how it shows on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up going with:

```
<script>
var latitude={tag_latitude}, //the tag is for the business catalyst web app 
    longitude={tag_longitude};

var marker;

function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('propertymap'), {    
   //change propertymap to your map id
   center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
   zoom: 15 //set to preferred zoom level
});

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   draggable: true,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
   position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
 });

 marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce); //for marker drop animation, can be removed

jQuery('#panel3').on('toggled', function(){ //change #panel3 to your tab id
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    map.setCenter(center); //must recenter map after tab loads
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize',{});
 });

}

function toggleBounce() { // for marker drop animation, can be removed
 if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
   marker.setAnimation(null);
 } else {
 marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

i was having the same problem before and i fixed it by adding this piece of code

```
 function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('propertymap'), {
    center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
    zoom: 15
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
  });
  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);

  jQuery('document').ready(function(){ 
     google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize',{});
  });

}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

and it's preferable to put it at the end of your script , but the essentiel is to trigger a resize event on your component after load , which will be done by that line.

Comment: I tried adding that to the end of the page and to the end of that script but it has the same issue.  Is there some detail on how to implement it that I could be missing?

Comment: to debug it clearly try to add it at the end of the script with no event triggered like this "google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize',{});" so then tell me what you got at the console

Comment: That doesn't give any errors but does the same thing as before.

Comment: try it with some triggered event as before like load or click at the same line you are having now it should work since it's logically

Comment: That is the part I am having a hard time with, I am extremely new to javascript.

Comment: see my edit again and let me know if it doesn't work !!

Comment: It doesn't work with load.  With click it doesn't work until you click on it, and then isn't centered properly. Is there a way to register the click on the tab instead of the map?

Comment: give it a try by triggering on all the document so this would be my last chance with it !!

Comment: Nope, same as before :/.  I do appreciate all the help though, it does get me closer.

Comment: @AlexCarpenter are you putting your project online so i can check it !!

Comment: I was able to use what you gave me to solve it.  I just had to change #propertymap to #panel3 and 'load' to 'toggled' then recenter the map.  If you want to substitute
 jQuery('#panel3').on('toggled', function(){ 
 var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.setCenter(center);
      google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize',{});
  });
I will select this as the correct answer.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't have gotten there without your help.  This still needs to be edited to show the right answer. Can you do that or should I submit a new one?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it using Foundation tab change event:

```
var map = null;
$('[data-tabs]').on('change.zf.tabs', function () {
    // check that user selected Map tab for the first time
    // if yes then load and show Google map 
    // let's assume map is located in Tab#2, thus we need Tab with index of 1
    if (!map && $('.tabs-title.is-active').index() == 1) {   // change "1" to your tab# + 1
        // create your map here
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMap'));
        // add map markers and so on...                
    }

    // optional: if you have Foundation equalizer plugin on the page 
    // then uncomment line below to reInit the plugin 
    // Foundation.reInit('equalizer');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem recently. It helped me to initiate the Google map only ONCE when clicking the tab;

```
    $('#tabWithMap').one('click', function(){
//create map and markers etc.

});
```